# fs dump equivalent in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, csv, dump, fs, csv-write-stream

### Objective

Forcing fs (and the libraries using it) to write everything to files before terminating application.

### Background

I am writing an object to a CSV file using the npm package [csv-write-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-write-stream).

Once the library is done writing the CSV file, I want to terminate my application using `process.exit()`.

### Code

To achieve the aforementioned objective, I have written the following:

```
let writer = csvWriter({
  headers: ['country', 'postalCode']
});

writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('myOutputFile.csv'));

//Very big array with a lot of postal code info
let currCountryCodes = [{country: Portugal, postalCode: '2950-286'}, {country: Barcelona, postalCode: '08013'}];

for (let j = 0; j < currCountryCodes.length; j++) {
  writer.write(currCountryCodes[j]);
}

writer.end(function() {
  console.log('=== CSV written successfully, stopping application ===');
  process.exit();
});
```

### Problem

The problem here is that if I execute `process.exit()`, the library wont have time to write to the file, and the file will be empty.

Since the library uses `fs`, my solution to this problem, is to force a `fs.dump()` or something similar in NodeJs, but after searching, I found nothing similar.

### Questions

1. How can I force fs to dump  (push) all the content to the file before exiting the application?
2. If the first option is not possible, is there a way to wait for the application to write and then close it ?

Comment: Just curious. Is there a specific reason why you need to call `process.exit()`? I guess the process will still terminate even if you don't call exit explicitly.

Comment: Since I am running a nodeJS app, the server will keep running forever once initiated, and I need to terminate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your guess is right. 
When you call `process.exit()`, the piped write stream hasn't finished writing yet.

If you really want to terminate your server explicitly, this will do.

```
let r = fs.createWriteStream('myOutputFile.csv');
writer.pipe(r);

...

writer.end(function() {
  r.end(function() {
    console.log('=== CSV written successfully, stopping application ===');
    process.exit();
  });
});
```

Comment: Precisely what fixed my problem !